# $\mathbb{Z}$ solutions for a system of equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

An example: Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be variables satisfying the equations given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_3&x_2\\
x_3&x_2&x_1\\
x_2&x_1&x_3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and we want to find solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the equations gotten from equating the entries and $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$.

Then we can show that this has only solutions $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$. This can be obtained from the equation $x_2^2-x_3^2=x_2-x_3$.

Question: Now suppose we want to find solution of the equations

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_4&x_2&x_5&x_3\\
x_4&x_2&x_5&x_3&x_1\\
x_2&x_5&x_3&x_1&x_4\\
x_5&x_3&x_1&x_4&x_2\\
x_3&x_1&x_4&x_2&x_5
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and we want to find solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the equations gotten from equating the entries and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=1$.

How to solve this system of equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $x_5=1-(x_1+x_1+x_3+x_4)$ we obtain five polynomial equations in the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. All solutions over the complex numbers are given as follows:
$$
(x_1,\ldots ,x_5)=(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1),(1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5).
$$
Here the only non integer solution is $x_i=\frac{1}{5}$ for all $i$. This follows easily from using a Groebner basis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't have any idea about Groebner basis. Can you please elaborate on how to find a Groebner basis and apply it here? A reference for the same will do. :)

Comment: Actually, it is enough to take the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of two polynomials. Then you obtain a polynomial in one variable less. Iterating it will also lead to the solution. Of course, there might be a general proof without computation. How is the matrix defined in general?

Comment: I guess, in general we can fix an ordering of one row and cyclically permute it to get other rows such that $a_{ii}=i$